# Glassfish server domain stops running for no obvious reason

Tags: java, linux, dns, glassfish, shutdown

I have a glassfish 4 server installed on a Linux server. Apart from the Glassfish server default domain1,   I created another domain - domain4.

Domain1 and domain4 have .WAR files of same application deployed on each of them.

But the domain4 keeps stopping for no obvious reason. I have to manually restart it with the 'sh asadmin start-domain domain4' command . This happens several times a day and it's tiring and frustrating to users. The domain1 doesn't have that issue.

I searched for solutions on google and StackOverflow.Most answers pointed to memory issues.

- I increased the swappiness of the Linux so it can use more of the virtual memory if it needs more memory. However this did not work .
- I asked the web host to increase the RAM from 2GB to 4 GB. This still did not solve the issue.
- I undeployed the app from domain4, but the domain still goes down after a while.
- I created another domain - domain5 without deploying any app on it. Yet, domain5 still goes down. Which means the problem is not from the app. But domain1 keeps running without issues.

*I even stopped domain1, to see if it was the cause and allowed domain5 to run . But after a while, domain5 still went down.

While monitoring the Linux server memory usage, I noticed the system doesn't even use up to 60% of RAM. The Glassfish server log and glassfish log didn't show any errors that point to any cause.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the cause of this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a service for the glassfish domain using the command:

asadamin>create-service *domainName*

it's been stable now for weeks.